# How to prioritize rules in VS Code language extensions

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, textmate

I am trying to create a language extension for VS Code. The comments in this language are single-line comments and start with a semicolon, like this

```
command ;comment
```

for this, I put the following into the repository section of my tmLanguage.json:

```
"comments": {
    "name": "comment.lang",
    "begin": ";",
    "end": "\n"
}
```

and include it in the patterns section

```
{
    "include": "#comments"
}
```

this works, so far. Now on top of that, the language also features special blocks, which start with ";!" and with ";;" respectively. Those I want to be treated differently:

```
"magicString": {
    "name": "magicString.lang",
    "begin": ";!",
    "end": "\n"
},
"commentHeader": {
    "name": "commentHeader.lang",
    "begin": ";;",
    "end": "\n"
},
```

Again, I include them in the patterns section

```
{
    "include": "#magicString"
},
{
    "include": "#commentHeader"
}
```

Now the obvious problem is that those two start exactly like a comment. As a consequence, they seem to be recognized and treated as comments. The scope inspector confirms that the tokens are indeed handled as "comment.lang".

How can I get around this? Is there a way to prioritize one rule above another? I looked up the topic in the [TextMate documentation](https://macromates.com/manual/en/language_grammars), but I don't get it. I tried specifying in the `begin` regex the number of semicolon repetitions -- I thought this should work but it does not.

```
    "magicString": {
        "name": "magicString.lang",
        "begin": ";!",
        "end": "\n"
    },
    "commentHeader": {
        "name": "commentHeader.lang",
        "begin": ";{2}",
        "end": "\n"
    },
    "comments": {
        "name": "comment.lang",
        "begin": ";{1}",
        "end": "\n"
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution in your case would be to make sure the three `begin` regular expressions are mutually exclusive.  For example, you could change your repository patterns as follows:

```json
    "magicString": {
        "name": "comment.magic.lang",
        "begin": ";!",
        "end": "\n"
    },
    "commentHeader": {
        "name": "comment.header.lang",
        "begin": ";;",
        "end": "\n"
    },
    "comments": {
        "name": "comment.lang",
        "begin": ";[^;!]",
        "end": "\n"
    }
```

Note the regex for `comments`: `;[^;!]` means *"a `;` character that is not followed by a `;` or `!` character"*.

(The change in scope names in the above snippet is not directly related to your question.  It is just my impression of what would be considered better practice, although I caution that I am a complete beginner on TextMate.)